# Update attribute : add source

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, source-model

I have a product attribute that have been added directly in the database threw a migration process.

I want to update that attribute to give him a source.

But this seems not to be working.

```
$attribute = $this->productAttributeRepositoryInterface->get('my_attribute_code');
$attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
$this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(
    Product::ENTITY,
    $attributeId,
    [
        'source' => 'Cpy\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyAttribute\Options',
    ]
);
```

I have no error but the backend model in database seems to stay null.

Also tried :

```
        try{
            $attribute = $this->productAttributeRepositoryInterface->get('encombrement');
            $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(
                4,
                $attributeId,
                'source',
                'Cpy\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyAttribute\Options'
            );
        }catch(Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Full method

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.2') < 0) {
       // ....
    }
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3') < 0) {
        try{
            $attribute = $this->productAttributeRepositoryInterface->get('encombrement');
            $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(
                4,
                $attributeId,
                'source',
                'Cpy\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyAttribute\Options'
            );
        }catch(Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace VVendor\Extension\Setup; 

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
        ) 
    { 
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) { 
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4,32,'source','Cpy\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyAttribute\Options',null); 
        $setup->endSetup(); 
    } 

}
```

**NOTE:**

```
4 = Entity Type Id of Attribute.
32 = Attribute Id.
```

Comment: Seems not to work neither, i still see the model value empty in database after updating this way :/ In the product form the select is still empty too

Comment: Confirm you replace proper data into above code and then run caching, indexing, upgrade and deploy commands.

Comment: I'm in dev mode so no deploy. I've run the setup upgrade and flush cache after it thats what i still have in the database : `123,4,encombrement,,,int,,,select,Encombrement,,,0,1,"",0,
`

Comment: updated code in the question

Comment: Where is $setup->endSetup();  this line into your code?

Comment: at the end of method : Oh wait...is this might come from the fact i'm doing it inside schema instead of data ? Though it's touching source and not really the data

Comment: have confirm, you will get proper value $attributeId into this one? try to put static value there first and then check.

Comment: Dumping the attribute id seems to be fine : Module 'Cpy_Encombrement':
Upgrading schema.. string(3) "123"

Comment: I ended up figure it out, for some reason that I wouldn't be able to explain; we need to provide 'source_model' for update instead of 'source' when we add. Ok it's the database field name but...it's not very consistent from magento to act like that. Though, this is the solution that make your code works (and probably my initial code too I think.

Answer (score 0):

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Extension" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {
            $this->updateAttribute($setup);
        }
    }

    public function updateAttribute($setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(4, 'encombrement', 'source_model', 'Cpy\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyAttribute\Options');
    }
}
```

Note:

- 4 or 'catalog_product' for Entity Type
- better to use attribute_code instead of attribute_id